# How to read the implementation code/source code for inbuilt functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For instance if I would like to read the source code for the default `curry` function in Prelude, where do I refer? Is there a way to read it's implementation? I tried to search it in Hoogle, but it doesn't give the exact implementation, just the input and output types. I am using GHCI on stack to run haskell.-

[Hoogle curry](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:curry)

Comment: Click the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Tuple.html#curry) link on the right-hand side.

Comment: Worth mentioning: the souce link is not there every time. for example `mtl` re-exports functions from `transformers` and only hackage doc of `transformers` provides the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @Lee mentioned in the comments, there is a link for [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Tuple.html#curry) for many of the functions on hackage.
[image]

Following this will take you to the source code for `curry`:

```
-- | 'curry' converts an uncurried function to a curried function.
curry                   :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry f x y             =  f (x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for! It's placed in a way that makes it invisible, no link color, small font. It almost looks like a comment.